# how to validate a textfield that can accept 11 digit neither less nor greater than 11 in webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

i want to validate a text-field in Web form that can accept 11 digit neither less than 11 nor greater than 11

thanks in advance.

Comment: Use jquery for better performance i.e. if(`$("#ControlID").val().length==11) return true; else return false;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont go to server side for this little things.. 
Do this at client side..

```
<input type="text" onblur="return txtBlur(this)"/>


function txtBlur(txtobj) {
        if (txtobj.value.length != 11) {
            alert("Please Enter 11 digit value");
            txtobj.focus();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression in C# like this:

```
string expression  = @"^\d{11}$";

Match match = Regex.Match(TextBox1.Text.Trim(),expression);

if (match.Success)
{
  Label1.Text = "valid";
}
else
{
Label1.Text = "invalid";
}
```

or you can use **RegularExpressionValidator** as another person posted.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate = "TextBox1" ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" ValidationExpression = "^\d{11}$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="11 characters required."></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression validator:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display = "Dynamic" ControlToValidate = "TextBox3" ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" ValidationExpression = "^[0-9]*${11,11}$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Minimum 11 and Maximum 11 characters required."></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
in aspx file

```
<input id="btnSubmit" text= onserverclick="btnSubmit_ServerClick" runat="server" />
```

in cs file

```
 protected void btnSubmit_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 string str = yourtextboxvalue.Value;
        if (str.Length == 11)
        {
//ok 
        }
else{
return;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTML5, you can do the client-side validation using unobtrusive JavaScript validators. Just include the reference to the unobtrusive validation script files, and add the following attributes to your textbox:

```
<input id="txtField" type="number" data-val="true" data-val-number="Please enter a number" data-val-length-min="11" data-val-length-max="11" data-val-length="Input length should be 11">
```

This will ensure that an error message is shown in the validation summary without a postback.

However, I recomment you still perform this validation on the server side too, to ensure the validation in case JavaScript has been turned off on the client side.

Here is an article that might be useful:
http://denverdeveloper.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/some-things-ive-learned-about-jquery-unobtrusive-validation/